# 100% width not fully expanding to 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website with bootstrap and I've run into a problem. When I use width: 100% on one of my divs, the background color doesn't fully expand to 100%. It only expands to 90% or so (5% of the left and 5% of the right side show the body background color). I apppriciate any help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <title>Galaxy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <style type="text/css">
</style>
<script>
    var sound = new Audio();
    sound.src = "rick.mp3";
 </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/galaxy3.jpg">
                        <div class="slide1"></div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <div class="bannertext">
                                <h1>Santorodesign</h1>
                                <p>A website made by Michael</p>
                                <div class="mobileHide"> <button id="headerbutton-nederlands">Nederlands</button></div>
                                <div class="mobileHide"> <button id="headerbutton-english">English</button></div>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="slide2"></div>
                    <img src="images/galaxy2.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <div class="bannertext2">
                            <h1>Explore the galaxy<h1>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>

                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
                </a>            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="firstrow">
            <div class="planettext">
                Planets
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/mercury.png"> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Mercury</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/earth.png"> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about the Earth</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/venus.png"> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Venus</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/mars.png"> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Mars</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/jupiter.png"><br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about jupiter</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/saturn.png"><br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Saturn</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/uranus.png"><br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Uranus</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/neptune.png"><br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Neptune</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

            </div>
                <div class="planet col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="pluto">
                <div class="plutotext">
                    Poor Pluto
                </div>
                <href="##" onmousedown="sound.play()"><img src="images/pluto.png"></a> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Pluto</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: #DCDCDC;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none
}
#firstrow {
   font-size: 2em;
   padding: 0px 0 0 0;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   color: black;
   position: relative;
}
#firstrow span {
    font-family: Impact, Impact5, Charcoal6, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
#firstrow p {
    font-family: Helvetica,
}
@media all and (max-width: 2000px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands {
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 0px;
         right: -90px;
         line-height: 40px;
    }
}
.planettext {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.plutotext {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 00;
}
#pluto {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;

}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands { display: none; }
    #headerbutton-english { display: none; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 2000px) {
     #headerbutton-nederlands {
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 0px;
         right: -70px;
         line-height: 40px;
     }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1450px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 30px;
        right: -55px;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands {
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 25px;
        right: -55px;
        }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1080px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands {
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 20px;
        right: -40px;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 2000px) {
     #headerbutton-english {
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 0px;
         right: 100px;
         line-height: 40px;
     }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1450px) {
    #headerbutton-english {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 14px;
        right: 80px;
        line-height: 30px
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #headerbutton-english {
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 25px;
        right: 50px;
        }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1080px) {
    #headerbutton-english {
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 20px;
        right: 50px;
    }
}


.planet {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
    .planet img {
        height: 300px;
        max-width: none;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }


    .bannertext {
         font-size: 1.3em;
         line-height: 15px;
         position: relative;
    }
    .bannertext h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    .bannertext2 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
 .mobileShow { display: none;}
 .mobileHide { display: inline;}
     /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
    @media only screen
        and (max-device-width : 480px){
        .mobileShow { display: inline;}
        .mobileHide { display: none;}
        .planet img{
            height: 200px;
        }
        }
#headerbutton-nederlands {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #778899;
    width: 13%;
    text-align: center;  
    border: white 2px solid ;    
}
#headerbutton-english {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #778899;
    width: 13%;
    text-align: center;  
    border: white 2px solid ;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: why all these media queries?

Comment: Maybe you could use more than 100%?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to add following in your planet pluto div

```
                <div class="row"> /* EDIT*/
                <div id="pluto">
            <div class="plutotext">
                Poor Pluto
            </div>
            <href="##" onmousedown="sound.play()"><img src="images/pluto.png"></a> <br>
            <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Pluto</button></a>
            </div>
              </div>   /* EDIT */
```

Here's [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWNyxY) answer

One thing that i noted is that though you used bootstrap grid system, you never used bootstrap row class, which is amazing. It's better you would use boostrap inbuilt row class instead of all these classes that you created. Your code looks messy because of that.

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: #DCDCDC;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none
}
#firstrow {
   font-size: 2em;
   padding: 0px 0 0 0;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   color: black;
   position: relative;
}
#firstrow span {
    font-family: Impact, Impact5, Charcoal6, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
#firstrow p {
    font-family: Helvetica,
}
@media all and (max-width: 2000px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands {
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 0px;
         right: -90px;
         line-height: 40px;
    }
}
.planettext {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.plutotext {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 00;
}
#pluto {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;

}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands { display: none; }
    #headerbutton-english { display: none; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 2000px) {
     #headerbutton-nederlands {
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 0px;
         right: -70px;
         line-height: 40px;
     }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1450px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 30px;
        right: -55px;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands {
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 25px;
        right: -55px;
        }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1080px) {
    #headerbutton-nederlands {
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 20px;
        right: -40px;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 2000px) {
     #headerbutton-english {
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 0px;
         right: 100px;
         line-height: 40px;
     }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1450px) {
    #headerbutton-english {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 14px;
        right: 80px;
        line-height: 30px
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #headerbutton-english {
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 25px;
        right: 50px;
        }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1080px) {
    #headerbutton-english {
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 20px;
        right: 50px;
    }
}


.planet {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
    .planet img {
        height: 300px;
        max-width: none;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }


    .bannertext {
         font-size: 1.3em;
         line-height: 15px;
         position: relative;
    }
    .bannertext h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    .bannertext2 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
 .mobileShow { display: none;}
 .mobileHide { display: inline;}
     /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
    @media only screen
        and (max-device-width : 480px){
        .mobileShow { display: inline;}
        .mobileHide { display: none;}
        .planet img{
            height: 200px;
        }
        }
#headerbutton-nederlands {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #778899;
    width: 13%;
    text-align: center;  
    border: white 2px solid ;    
}
#headerbutton-english {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #778899;
    width: 13%;
    text-align: center;  
    border: white 2px solid ;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <title>Galaxy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <style type="text/css">
</style>
<script>
    var sound = new Audio();
    sound.src = "rick.mp3";
 </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/galaxy3.jpg">
                        <div class="slide1"></div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <div class="bannertext">
                                <h1>Santorodesign</h1>
                                <p>A website made by Michael</p>
                                <div class="mobileHide"> <button id="headerbutton-nederlands">Nederlands</button></div>
                                <div class="mobileHide"> <button id="headerbutton-english">English</button></div>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="slide2"></div>
                    <img src="images/galaxy2.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <div class="bannertext2">
                            <h1>Explore the galaxy<h1>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>

                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
                </a>            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="firstrow">
            <div class="planettext">
                Planets
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/mercury.png"> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Mercury</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/earth.png"> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about the Earth</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/venus.png"> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Venus</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/mars.png"> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Mars</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/jupiter.png"><br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about jupiter</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/saturn.png"><br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Saturn</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/uranus.png"><br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Uranus</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/neptune.png"><br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Neptune</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="planet col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

            </div>
                <div class="planet col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  
                  <div class="row">
                    <div id="pluto">
                <div class="plutotext">
                    Poor Pluto
                </div>
                <href="##" onmousedown="sound.play()"><img src="images/pluto.png"></a> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Pluto</button></a>
                </div>
                  </div>  
                  
                  
            </div>
          
          
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the #pluto to be 100%?

```
<div class="planet col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div id="pluto">
          <div class="plutotext">Poor Pluto</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Can you use the dev tools to check the width and padding of the parent div: . I'm guessing the issue is there.